# Android: How do I restart my app by activity that I stopped by pressing the home?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-activity

When i stop my application pressing home button, i need that the app restart from the same activity when i open it again.

Now my application always start from main activity :(

(i don't know why but on emulator work correctly...)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options for preserving the state of an application - the ost common of these include using the bundle passed in OnCreate to initiate the application correctly.

I suggest you look at the android developers documentation as regards to activity lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

When you begin an Activity, store a SharedPreference that records which Activity you are on.  Check this preference when you enter your main Activity and, if set, jump to that Activity.

(If you are just looking for a way to get back to your Activity and don't care about the code, use the Recents menu to get back to your Activity.  On devices with dedicated keys, long-press Home.)